# 12С: Не работает create table из примера

Tags: oracle, table, oracle12c

Пример находится здесь: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/automatic-list-partitioning-12cr2

Текст

Alternatively we could recreate the table **using the AUTOMATIC keyword**.

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  id            NUMBER,
  country_code  VARCHAR2(5),
  customer_id   NUMBER,
  order_date    DATE,
  order_total   NUMBER(8,2),
  CONSTRAINT orders_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (country_code) AUTOMATIC
(
  PARTITION part_usa VALUES ('USA'),
  PARTITION part_uk_and_ireland VALUES ('GBR', 'IRL')
);
```

Пытаюсь воспроизвести, ошибка: `ORA-00922: отсутствует или неверна опция`

БД: `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit 
Production`

Не подскажете, проблема в примере или во мне? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в версии БД.

В статье:

> Automatic list partitioning was introduced in Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (**12.2**)

У Вас:

> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release **12.1**.0.2.0 - 64bit 
>   Production